# JQuery click on selectable list

Tags: jquery, html, click, jquery-ui-selectable

I have an html page with a 4-item menu and 4 articles:

```
<nav>
    <ul> 
        <li id="startButton"><div>Start</div></li>
        <li id="servicesButton"><div>Services</div></li>
        <li id="offersButton"><div>Offers</div></li>
        <li id="contactButton"><div>Contact</div></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<article id="start">
    <p>Start text</p>
</article>
<article id="services" hidden="true">
    <p>Services text</p>
</article>
<article id="offers" hidden="true">
    <p>Offers text</p>
</article>
<article id="contact" hidden="true">
    <p>Contacts textº</p>
</article>
```

When the page is loaded only the first article is visible. With JQuery I want to change the visible article when its respective button is clicked. Also I want the li to be selectable. This is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    $('ul').selectable();
    $('li#startButton').click(function() {
        $('#start').show();
        $('#services').hide();
        $('#offers').hide();
        $('#contact').hide();
    });
    $('li#servicesButton').click(function() {
        $('#start').hide();
        $('#services').show();
        $('#offers').hide();
        $('#contact').hide();
    });
    $('li#offersButton').click(function() {
        $('#start').hide();
        $('#services').hide();
        $('#offers').show();
        $('#contact').hide();
    });
    $('li#contactButton').click(function() {
        $('#start').hide();
        $('#services').hide();
        $('#offers').hide();
        $('#contact').show();
    });

});
```

The problem with this script is that the hide and show part doesn't work together with the selectable part. If I eliminate the selectable line, the rest works perfectly. Does anyone know how to solve this "incompatibility" between selectable and click?

I am using JQuery 2.1.1 and JQuery UI 1.11.2

Regards,
Deborah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hidden` attribute is not toggled by jQuery, which uses the `display` property of an element to show and hide. You'll need to change that using a CSS class or inline styles.

Toggling sets of elements by ID is very inefficient from a code perspective. Try this instead:

```
$('nav ul').selected().children('li').click(function() {
    var myIndex = $(this).index();
    var $articles = $(this).closest('nav').siblings('article');
    $articles.hide();
    $articles.eq(myIndex).show();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gfpz5xm4/4/)

You'll notice that I'm selecting articles based on the index of the list item, and that I'm chaining the `selected()` and `click()` methods.

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work like the example... anyway I used a variation of your code:  $('nav li').click(function() {
  var myIndex = $(this).index();
  var $articles = $(this).closest('nav').siblings('article');
  $articles.hide();
  $articles.eq(myIndex).show();
  $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('ui-selected');
  $(this).addClass('ui-selected');
 });

Comment: You're adding and removing classes manually, which is what the Selected plugin is there for.